# PHP/mySQL issue with UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

after a week searching and test many way, still i stuck in this problem. a problem like this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809320/php-mysql-utf-8-some-characters-are-still-bug). i tried with that answer but my problem still not solved.

ok, let me explain. i trying to insert some utf-8 (persian/arabic), i have to mention this that i have not any problem with these character in my html/php page, this mean all un dynamic character are ok.

input is:

> دوشنبه , ۱۱ اسفند ۱۳۹۳ , ۲۲:۲۵

in database is:

> Ø¯ÙˆØ´Ù†Ø¨Ù‡ , Û±Û± Ø§Ø³ÙÙ†Ø¯ Û±Û³Û¹Û³ , Û²Û²:Û²Ûµ

output:

> دوشنبه , ۱۱ اسفند ۱۳۹۳ , ۲۲:۲۵ �

it contains " � "

if i edit this field in database and enter new data, it will like this:

> دوشنبه , ۱۱ اسفند ۱۳۹۳ , ۲۲:۲۵

but in output will show:

> ????

i tried many way, like **SET NAMES 'utf8** and **ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");** and etc.. but still have this problem.

Comment: what is the encoding of the database table you're inserting the records in?

Comment: CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE='utf8_persian_ci'; @Tivie also tested with general_ci

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` `utf8_decode($content)`